# Android - Set a Drawable to multiple buttons

Tags: android, android-drawable, rippledrawable

Setting a same `Drawable` to multiple buttons/views as backgrounds (using `setBackground(Drawable)` has problem with ripple effect, when I click Button A, the ripple effect of Button B would be shown.

**Note:** I tested `mutate()` but nothing worked

Comment: Can you put click listeners on both buttons and make sure both of the buttons aren't receiving clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`Drawable newDrawable = oldDrawable.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();`

Comment: It works like a charm! Do you have any explanation why it works?

Comment: Yes, because `newDrawable()` make deep copy of original drawable.